# how to attach to a screen if there is one already or start a new one if it doesnt exist without detaching from other devices

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am trying to configure screen on my RPi and I want to use Screen as my default shell so that I can get the same data of what I was doing on PI whenever I login from any of the device connected in same network. I understand that I can start screen by default in by .profile file. I want to know which argument I should use so that if i login from another device, then it shouldnt start a new one but connected to an existing one. If there is no existing one, then it should a new one. However I dont want it to get detached from other devices. This way i can ensure that there is only one screen and everybody access the same screen and can see who is doing what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a if-else loop

pseudo code:-

```
if ((screen -ls)!=null){screen -r tosomescreen}
else{ //start new screen}
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Was looking for an inbuilt switch which would avoid this code. But looks like there isnt one. Hence will follow as you have suggested. Thanks

Comment: There may be, but I am not aware of it :)

Answer (score 2):

The `-R` option attaches to the first detached session found, or else creates a new session.

```
screen -R -S newsession
```

This will attach to a detached session if found, ignoring the `-S` option. Otherwise, a new session named "new session" is created and attached.